# Error removing dynamically added code - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I was trying do delete a certain div after an ajax's success action is done. Some code:

Here I try to remove it form the DOM:

```
$('.close-modal').on('click', function () {

    console.log("modal closed");
    $( "#animation" ).remove();

});
```

All this code is inside the `$(document).ready{......}` function

Live example (at the bottom, in Contacto): [DEMO](http://testmycodenow.tk/shield)

The problem is that, when the form is sent, an animation appears but I cannot remove it by closing the modal.
I've been investigating and everyone says that it's because the event need to be triggered by `.on (bind)`, but that's in case I need to remove the element by pressing it! And in that case, I need to delete it by doing another action (close the modal).

```
var url = "formulario.php";
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",

    url: url,

    data: $("#formulario").serialize(),

    success: function(data)
    {                       
      $("#formulario_contacto").hide();

      $('.modal-content').append("<div id = "animation" class='icon icon--order-success svg'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='72px' height='72px' class = 'posicion'><g fill='none' stroke='#8EC343' stroke-width='2'><circle cx='36' cy='36' r='35' style='stroke-dasharray:240px, 240px; stroke-dashoffset: 480px;'></circle><path d='M17.417,37.778l9.93,9.909l25.444-25.393' style='stroke-dasharray:50px, 50px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px;'></path></g></svg></div>");              
    }
});

event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method provided by jQuery.

Using which you can remove the event handler, as below.

```
$('.close-modal').off('click');
```

Also if you wish to **remove all** event handles then you can just use

```
$('.close-modal').off();  // with no arguments
```

Comment: I see, but that's not about handlers I think! The closure of the modal is the trigger, and what I want to remove is the div with id = "animación"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is .close-modal generated dynamically as well? In that case, you should delegate the event, something like:

```
$('.close-modal').on('click','body', function () {

    console.log("modal closed");
    $( "#animation" ).remove();

});
```

obviously, change `body` to whatever element is more convenient to you (maybe .modal-content? or any static element parent of .close-modal)

Saludos compatriota!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to remove the success animation when the modal closes and reset the form. Based on your current demo:

1) You should listen to Bootstrap's modal closed event instead of hijacking the click on the close button (the modal can also be closed by clicking on the backdrop or pressing ESC, which won't trigger your handler). So you should do something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // Modal was closed
})
```

2) In your demo, the animation is added with id == "contenedor-tick". So if you want to remove that animation when the modal closes:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#contenedor-tick').remove();
})
```

3) But in order to reset the form you will need to keep it in the DOM. Currently you are adding the animation by replacing the entire contents of the modal, thus loosing the form. I would recommend to have the animation already present in your HTML (don't add it with JS), and simply have it hidden with CSS by default. When the form is submitted successfully, show the animation and hide the form. When the modal is closed, hide the animation and show the form (and reset all the fields as well).